# Login With Google plus in android Google Api Client Disconnected

Tags: android, google-plus, google-authentication

I am implementing login with Google plus in my android app. When i implement it, at that time work fine after 1 week exception arise is Google Api client must connect

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.
>   05-19 16:45:41.447 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
>   05-19 16:45:41.447 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus.zzf(Unknown Source) 05-19
>   16:45:41.447 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzawj.getCurrentPerson(Unknown Source)
>   05-19 16:45:41.447 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at
>   com.cmexpertise.dealsnow.ui.activity.LoginActivity.getProfileInformation(LoginActivity.java:1361)
>   05-19 16:45:41.447 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at
>   com.cmexpertise.dealsnow.ui.activity.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:1297)
>   05-19 16:45:41.447 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6235)
>   05-19 16:45:41.447 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3584)
>   05-19 16:45:41.448 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3631)
>   05-19 16:45:41.448 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
>   05-19 16:45:41.448 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
>   05-19 16:45:41.448 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 05-19
>   16:45:41.448 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 05-19 16:45:41.448
>   27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 05-19
>   16:45:41.448 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 05-19 16:45:41.448
>   27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 05-19 16:45:41.448
>   27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
>   05-19 16:45:41.448 27753-27753/com.cmexpertise.dealsnow W/System.err: 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)

This issue happen 4 to 5 time how it solve

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Can you show the code?